# Shell script: insert string below a line depending on line number

Tags: bash, shell

I am relatively new to shell scripting so apologies. I have found older questions which insert strings based on a string which appears in a line, but my lines are all of the same format.

I have a file in which I want to insert a string 'insert_text. below each line. I used vim to search for the line break and insert the string below in the following:

```
%s/\n/\r insert_text.\r/
```

The above works fine. However, I have 250 lines in my file and 12 specific lines for which I *don't* wish to insert the string below. I could search for each specific line and remove the string, but I would like to write a shell script that could automate it.

This is as close as I've got

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in {179, 170, 183, 104, 187, 172, 173, 171, 11, 7, 105, 3}
do
     sed '\n/\r insert_text.\r/'
done
```

Obviously the above loop makes no sense, and the above code does the opposite of what I want, I want to insert the string into all the other lines.

Is there something similar to -v which would select all other lines in the for loop?

Comment: In which command are you using `%s/\n/\r insert_text.\r/` It doesn't look like `sed`

Comment: %s/\n/\r was used in the command line while in vim

Comment: Your question is not Linux-specific, so I removed the according tag. Read the tag's description please, it explains that a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -v ln='179,170,183,104,187,172,173,171,11,7,105,3' '
   ln !~ "(^|,)" NR "(,|$)"{$0 = $0 "\n insert_text."} 1' file
```

- We pass a line numbers where we want to skip adding new text using command line argument `ln`
- Using `!~` operator we ensure current line number doesn't match this comma delimited string
- If match fails we print current line and new text

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the lines contain the actual line numbers, literally?

Comment: Ah sorry I think I misinterpreted question, fixing it now

Comment: I got the following: awk 'ln' argument to '-v' not in 'var=value' form

Comment: It is already in `-v var=value` form and I've tested with BSD and gnu awk. Try this: `awk -v s='179,170,183,104,187,172,173,171,11,7,105,3' 's !~ "(^|,)" NR "(,|$)"{$0 = $0 "\n insert_text."} 1' file`

Comment: That's is a really slick solution. I had not seen the use of `"(^|,)" NR "(,|$)"` to compare the string contents from beginning to end and not NR in that form. (in fact I'm going to have to find where that is in the awk User Guide) That's a keeper.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot, this command will save a lot of tedious editing

Answer (score 1):

Using sed, `b` jumps out, `a` appends.

```
sed '179b;170b;183b;104b;187b;172b;173b;171b;11b;7b;105b;3b;ainsert_text' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN { %skip = map { $_ + 1 => 1 } 0, 179, 170, 183, 104, 187, 172, 173, 171, 11, 7, 105, 3 } print "\n" unless exists $skip{$.}' foo.txt
```

(The 0 in the list of lines to not print an extra newline after is important)